# Android Gridview with fixed no of rows and columns

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, layoutparams

I want to create a grid that contains same no of columns and rows. If i assign 6 to gridview then it should generate 6 no of columns and 6 no of rows which means 36 imageviews and Gridview should not scroll down. All imageviews should fit the gridview. Size of imageviews in the grid is same (both width and height) like a calender.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I have tried that code but I want fixed no of columns also. Let say If i pass 6 then gridview's no of columns and rows should be same as 6 and total imageviews would be 36. Which is working fine but it makes the gridview scrollable.

Comment: @NoumanBhatti : then why u r using `GridView` if u don't want *scroll* and BTW u can't control **no of rows** u can controll **no of columns**

Comment: so what do you suggest me then?

Comment: @NoumanBhatti inflate layout dynamically

Comment: means dont use the gridview and dynamically inflate the imageviews into a simple view(Relative/Linear)?

Comment: take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-programmatically-adding-layouts.html) @NoumanBhatti